# sails.js session data not saved into db

Tags: node.js, sails.js, connect-mongo

I might be doing something wrong. Please guide me in right direction.

I am trying to implement sails session feature with 'connect-mongo'. I did the implementation same as explained in the docs [Sails session mongo](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session). After successful authentication I am trying to save session data into mongoDb. But in my case it is not saved in mongo collection and collection always remains empty.

My configurations in `session.js`

```
    url: 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-tkjwp.mongodb.net/mydbname?retryWrites=true',
    collection: 'sessions',
    auto_reconnect: false,
    ssl: false,
    stringify: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
```

and how I am trying to save.

```
if(user.length && user[0].id){
    // save in DB
    req.session.authenticated = true;
    req.session.authinfo = user[0];

    req.session.save(function(err) {
        console.log(req.session);
        return res.json({
            status: 1,
            msg: 'Successfull.'
        });                  
    })                

}else{
      return res.send({ 
        status: 0,
        msg: 'Invalid'
      });
}
```

Also I am not getting any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working now. Only thing I missed the `adapter` option. But now I am using it with mysql. Below I posting my working code with MySql.

In `session.js`

```
adapter: 'express-mysql-session',
host: 'localhost',
port: 3306,
user: 'root',
password: 'xxxxxxxxx',
database: 'xyz',
ssl: false,
stringify: true,
cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
},
```